# C++ operator overload for another class ( object and operator from class A usinng data from class B

Tags: c++, class, object, operators

I'm new to C++ classes, objects and especially overcharging operators.

Given the following `main` function, I have to work around it, so that in the end, the program will compile and run correctly. Here is the `main` function:

```
 int main()
{
    TOperator *oper = new TOperator("Alexandru");
    TComanda *command = new TComanda("online", oper);
   command += new Item("usb stick", 220); // this is calling Item's constructor 
   command += new Item("tastatura", 175); 
   oper->afiseazaCommanda();// printing out the final cart
   return 0;
 }
```

The main problems I'm facing so far are:

1)How can I overload the `+=` operator, so that I could add up the strings ( same as in python when doin `+` for two strings ) and also sum up my two integers?

2)How should I write my `afiseazaComanda()` function from `TOperator`, so that It will work out properly? Because, so far, when trying to compile it, it is giving me an error that "`Item` was not declared in this scope".

I've tried to get some information about `global operator overloading` but didn't find much.

Searching through SO didn't really help, because it wasn't talking about overcharging the operator in such way, so that the object of class `TComanda` could overcharge the class `Item`, so I hope that I could find some clear help there.

Here is the code for my classes:

```
 class Item
{
public:
    string Product;
    int Price;

    Item(string product, int price)
    {
        Product = product;
        Price = price;
    }
    friend class TComanda;
};

class TOperator
{
    string Name;
public:

    TOperator(string n)
    {
        Name = n;
    }

    void afiseazaComanda()
    {
        cout << Item.Product << " " << Item.Price; // supposed to print out the final cart with both the products and summed prices
    }

    friend class TComanda;
};


class TComanda
{
    string online, name;
public:

    TComanda(string onoroff, TOperator *op)
    {
        online = onoroff;
        this->name = op->Name;
    }

    TComanda operator +=(Item &a)
    {
        a+=a.Product;
        a+=a.Price;
        return *this;
    } // still thinking how I could write that part of the code
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't implement custom operators for pointers, only objects. So, for instance, since you declared `command` as a `TComanda*` pointer, you would have to dereference `command` to access the `TComanda` object it is pointing at, eg:

```cpp
*command += new Item("usb stick", 220);
```

Except that you have `TComanda:::operator+=` declared to take an `Item&` reference, not an `Item*` pointer, so you would have to dereference the `Item*` pointer, too:

```cpp
*command += *(new Item("usb stick", 220));
```

Which is a memory leak, since you are losing access to the `Item` object you `new`'ed, so you can't `delete` it when you are done using it (in fact, your whole `main()` is leaking every object it `new`'s).  So, get rid of the `new` here:

```cpp
*command += Item("usb stick", 220);
```

In which case, you may as well get rid of `new` on `command` and `oper`, too:

```cpp
TOperator oper("Alexandru");
TComanda command("online", &oper);
command += Item("usb stick", 220);
command += Item("tastatura", 175);
```

That being said, your whole code design is incomplete for what you are attempting, as `TOperator` has no concept of `TComanda`, but even if it did, `TComanda` does not store its added `Item`s anywhere that `TOperator` can reach them.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
public:
    string Product;
    int Price;

    Item(const string &product, int price);
};

class TComanda;
class TOperator
{
    string Name;
    TComanda *Command = nullptr;

public:
    TOperator(const string &name);

    void afiseazaCommanda() const;

    friend class TComanda;
};

class TComanda
{
    string Online, Name;
    vector<Item> Items;
    TOperator &Operator;

public:
    TComanda(const string &onoroff, TOperator &op);
    ~TComanda();

    TComanda& operator +=(const Item &a);

    friend class TOperator;
};

Item::Item(const string &product, int price)
{
    Product = product;
    Price = price;
}

TOperator::TOperator(const string &name)
{
    Name = name;
}

void TOperator::afiseazaCommanda() const
{
    if (Command) {
        for(const auto &item : Command->Items) {
            cout << item.Product << " " << item.Price << endl;
        }
    }
}

TComanda::TComanda(const string &onoroff, TOperator &op)
    : Operator(op)
{
    Online = onoroff;
    Name = Operator.Name;
    Operator.Command = this;
}

TComanda::~TComanda()
{
    if (Operator.Command == this)
        Operator.Command = nullptr;
}

TComanda& TComanda::operator +=(const Item &a)
{
    Items.push_back(a);
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    TOperator oper("Alexandru");
    TComanda command("online", oper);
    command += Item("usb stick", 220);
    command += Item("tastatura", 175); 
    oper.afiseazaCommanda();
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/87FoRc)

---

**UPDATE:**

Given the restriction you have on the code in `main()`, try something like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
public:
    string Product;
    int Price;

    Item(const string &product, int price);
};

class TComanda;
class TOperator
{
    string Name;
    TComanda *Command = nullptr;

public:
    TOperator(const string &name);

    void afiseazaCommanda() const;

    friend class TComanda;
};

class TComanda
{
    string Online, Name;
    vector<Item*> Items;
    TOperator *Operator;

public:
    TComanda(const string &onoroff, TOperator *op);
    ~TComanda();

    TComanda& operator +=(Item *a);

    friend class TOperator;
};

Item::Item(const string &product, int price)
{
    Product = product;
    Price = price;
}

TOperator::TOperator(const string &name)
{
    Name = name;
}

void TOperator::afiseazaCommanda() const
{
    if (Command) {
        for(const auto *item : Command->Items) {
            cout << item->Product << " " << item->Price << endl;
        }
    }
}

TComanda::TComanda(const string &onoroff, TOperator *op)
{
    Online = onoroff;
    Operator = op;
    Name = Operator->Name;
    Operator->Command = this;
}

TComanda::~TComanda()
{
    for(auto *item : Items)
        delete item;
        
    if (Operator->Command == this)
        Operator->Command = nullptr;
}

TComanda& TComanda::operator +=(Item *a)
{
    Items.push_back(a);
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    TOperator *oper = new TOperator("Alexandru");
    TComanda *command = new TComanda("online", oper);
    *command += new Item("usb stick", 220);
    *command += new Item("tastatura", 175); 
    oper->afiseazaCommanda();
    delete command;
    delete oper;
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Khgk7Q)

Comment: thank you for your help, but the problem is in the fact, that I have to work around that `main` function as is, because that's what I've been assigned. I've contacted my proffessor about that, but knowing him, he might not respond till the next time that I have class with him.

Comment: "*I have to work around that main function as is, because that's what I've been assigned*" - Then you were given bad code to start with, as it cannot work as shown for the reasons I stated. I have adjusted my answer to work with your restriction, but those errors must be addressed or this is all moot.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this really worked.

Comment: Could you please explain, why did you put the `&` before variable names in all the 3 constructors? In what way does it help us? I'm really oblivious, because, as I knew, it should've have worked fine even without it. Just asking out of curiosity

Comment: @Vlad You didn't say which version of C++ you are using. Prior to move semantics added in C++11, it was more efficient to pass `std::string` by reference than by value. But in C++11 and later, it doesn't really matter anymore. But it is still a good item to pass an object by reference if you don't intend to copy/move it.

Comment: Understood, thank you.